# RDP to VPN computer

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, rdp

I have a desktop outside the network.  It VPNs in and is assigned a public facing IP.  When I attempt to RDP to the public facing IP it won't connect.  When I RDP into the server, or any other computer on the domain, I can RDP to the desktop attached to the VPN.  My only guess is that it is a setting in the Firewall or in the Remote Access setup. Does anyone know how I can set up the systems involved so I can use the public facing ip address to RDP.

Systems:

Server: Windows Server 2008 R2
VPN Software: Windows Role, Network Policy and Access Service.
Firewall is the built in windows firewall in windows on both machines.

Client: Windows 7 Ultimate

Comment: Can we have a few more details - when you say you receive a public IP when you connect to the VPN, why is that?  The VPN should be assigning you a private IP on the LAN segment you are connecting to.  That is after all what a VPN does.  When you say "VPN Software", do you mean a third-party VPN solution, or the built-in Windows RRAS?  Does the server have a public-facing IP (or is it on a DMZ)?

Answer (score 1):

Look at your firewall settings, there is scope in rule allowing you to connect using RDP, so enable all scopes (Local, Work and public), also look NLA (network location awareness)